# ExtJS 4.2 sorting Issue

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid

I have a grid which looks like this:

```
 status              createdBy
 +-+-----------+     +-+--------+
 |1|running    |     |1|84, 77  |
 |2|running    |     |2|22      |
 |3|not running|     |3|        |
 +-+-----------+     +-+--------+
```

In my store, I defined

```
sorters: [{
    property: 'status',
    direction: 'DESC'
}
```

In my controller, I get this data:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'api/user.php',
            root: 'username',
            success: function(response) {
                Ext.getCmp('viewport').initComps();
                var _username = response.responseText;
                _username = _username.replace(/\D/g, '');
                return _username;
            },
        });
```

The grid is sorted by status -so far so good- but I want the row where `_username === createdBy.value` to be shown on top,
followed by the rest of the grid, still ordered by status, but I just can't get my code working...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll more than likely need to specify a custom sorter function to handle the logic, as the simple property sorter you have defined can't possibly know about the custom logic you want applied. Check out the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter

Comment: how can I check the array elements of createdBy, if they're equal to the username? sry, I'm pretty new to ExtJS

Answer (score 0):

Like existdissolve pointed out, you may need to use sorter function., 
check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/143 ('admin' users are listed first in the fiddle)